# Why isn't the public version of my notification displayed on the lock screen?

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I'm using v7 of NotificationCompat to build a notification. I want it to have a public version with less information for the lock screen, and a private version with more information for the notifications list available when the phone is unlocked. The instructions in the android developer documentation are pretty straight forward... But they're not working for me. I get the private version all the time, even on the lock screen.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I'm running android version 6.0.1 on my Samsung Galaxy S6, and for the private version of my notification I'm setting a custom view via the RemoteViews class.

Here's my code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder publicNotificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle(expense.name)
                .setContentText(expense.amount)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.wally_icon)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.wally_icon)
                .setContent(remoteViews)
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE)
                .setPublicVersion(publicNotificationBuilder.build())
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
notificationManager.notify((int)expense.id, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: public notification is only for secured lockscrees, i.e.one that would need pattern or pin, is yours locked?

Comment: Mine has to be unlocked with my fingerprint, but I would have thought that would count as a lock screen.

Comment: FWIW, [this sample app of mine](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Notifications/Lollipop) seems to be working fine, though I don't have a device set up with a fingerprint lock on the lockscreen. The biggest difference that I see is that `RemoteViews`. I wouldn't expect that to mess things up, but I can't rule it out.

Comment: Ugh, thanks, but I tried removing the `setContent` and using the standard title and text instead, and I tried reverting to v4 of NotificationCompat like your example, made sure a content intent was set for both public and private, copied the `setDefaults` method from your example as well, and tried explicitly declaring the visibility of the public notification as NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC, but nothing seems to work. I always get the private notification on the lock screen :(

Comment: Maybe android version 6.0.1 doesn't support this? Although I could have sworn I saw in the notification documentation that this should work as far back as android 5.

Comment: I had a bit of a trouble with this. After fiddling with it for an hour I realised I had to set the notification settings in the device to "hide sensitive content". It may not be related to your question, but may help someone who may land up here and have similar problem as mine. It worked with a notification with `RemoteViews` too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what fixed it, but it's working for me now using just standard notification actions. Here's what I have:

```
Intent saveAmountIntent = new Intent(context, SaveAmountReceiver.class);
Intent changeAmountIntent = new Intent(context, ChangeAmountReceiver.class);
saveAmountIntent.putExtra("expenseId", expense.id);
changeAmountIntent.putExtra("expenseId", expense.id);
PendingIntent saveAmountPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, saveAmountIntent, 0);
PendingIntent changeAmountPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, changeAmountIntent, 0);

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
NotificationCompat.Builder publicNotificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) this.createBaseNotification(context, expense, saveAmountPendingIntent)
    .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) this.createBaseNotification(context, expense, saveAmountPendingIntent)
    .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE)
    .setPublicVersion(publicNotificationBuilder.build())
    .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.change_icon, context.getString(R.string.change), changeAmountPendingIntent).build())
    .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.save_icon, context.getString(R.string.save), saveAmountPendingIntent).build());
notificationManager.notify((int)expense.id, notificationBuilder.build());
```

And my base notification function:

```
private NotificationCompat.Builder createBaseNotification(Context context, Expense expense, PendingIntent deleteIntent) {
    return (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setContentTitle(expense.name)
        .setContentText(expense.amount)
        .setDeleteIntent(deleteIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(false)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.my_notif_icon)
        .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
}
```